# VLC passive streaming Debian Squeeze & Wheezy

Tags: debian, vlc

im trying to do some streaming.
Here is my command line :

```
cvlc  -vvv /var/www/Webtv/video/fr/test.avi --sout "#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:gather:http{dst=:8080/video_fr.ogg}" --sout-keep
```

It not works properly on an OVH server.

I keep getting those messages :

```
[0x6eaf70] mux_ogg mux debug: adding input
[0x6eaf70] mux_ogg mux debug: theora stream
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (17133)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (96028)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (93573)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (80988)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (68268)
[0x6e1f90] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: late picture skipped (48879)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (57167)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (53769)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (17675)
[0x6eaf70] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (4937)
[0x6e1f90] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: late picture skipped (283877)
[0x6e1f90] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: late picture skipped (253972)
[0x6e1f90] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: late picture skipped (255371)
[0x6e1f90] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: late picture skipped (214995)
```

It works perfectly on my own VirtualMachine (Debian Wheezy) , but it seems the CPU cant follow on an OVH server (Debian Squeeze).
Here is the server's configuration :

CPU : Atom 330/N2800 Dual Core -- 4 Threads -- 1,6+Ghz
RAM : 4Gb

Since my VM  RAM was 1Gb and still works, i dont know why it just cant follow on a better server.

PS : I heard about something on ffmpeg cant work properply if it wasnt built from the scratch. Does my problem could come from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem is CPU-related. It means some frames are skipped because the CPU can't keep up with real-time streaming, so try transcoding at lower quality or use a better machine ;-)